# Chef template resource not_if solo

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, test-kitchen

I have following chef recipe and I don't want to run template resource when it gets converged under chef solo. It does not seem to obey the not_if while running kitchen converge. It still tries to connect the chef server. Please help.

Recipe,

```
template '/etc/hosts' do
  not_if Chef::Config[:solo]
  source 'hosts.erb'
  mode '0644'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  variables({
      :nodes => search(:node, 'ipaddress:*')
            })
end
```

Template,

```
...
<% @nodes.each do |n| -%>
    <% if (n['fqdn'] && n['ipaddress']) -%>
        <%= n['ipaddress'] %> <%= n['fqdn']  %>
    <% end -%>
<% end -%>
...
```

.kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: centos-6.7
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a normal value to `not_if` means it gets interpreted as a command to run. What you want is the block form:

```
not_if { Chef::Config[:solo] }
```

That said, it isn't the problem. The deeper issue is that all values directly in the resource body get evaluated at compile time. You want to use the `lazy` helper to delay evaluation so they only get used if the resource is actually run:

```
variables(lazy {
  {:nodes => search(:node, 'ipaddress:*')}
})
```